# Push view infront of another one?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Is it possible to push a view over the active view and remove that pushed view when we are done with it? (something like a slide panel?)

I'd prefer doing that to destroying and recreating view all day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [card layout](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.Card) to define multiple components and display only one of them at a time. Or maybe you're rather looking for a [modal](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Container-cfg-modal) container that doesn't completely hide the content beneath it (but prevent to interact with it)?